# NSArray of NSDictionary - Returning NSDictionary when having only one dictionary in array, not Array of one object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I am relatively new to Objective C. I have a NSArray containing NSDictionary objects. I am calling web service to fetch data. I have a PickerView and this is its DataSource (I have numberOfRows implemented):

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
     NSString *proba = self.viewModel.searchResult.someArray[row];
     return nil;
}
```

This is my 'proba' with 3 NSDictionaries in Array:

[image]

This is my 'proba' with only 1 NSDictionary in Array

[image]

Problem is that I need to have 1 NSDictionoray object in Array when my service returns 1 Dictionary. How to fix this? Thanks

EDIT:
My array from service, this is my selector

```
- (void)SOAPManager:(SOAPManager *)client didSuccesWithoutError:(id)responseObject
{
SearchResult *result = [SearchResult new];
result.myArray = [responseObject allValues];
self.Result = result;
NSLog(@"Loaded successfully: %@", result.retailers);

}
```

'self.Result' is observed with RACObserver so I can use it my ViewModel.

This is result.Retailers with 3 dictionaries:

[image]

And this with 1 dictionary:

[image]

So yeah, when only oneObject, it returns only Dictionary

Comment: Your question is not clear at all unfortunately. The picker code doesn't seem to have anything to do with your `proba` data structure. Are you trying to parse the server response into something different? If so, provide that code (the code you use to build that array).

Comment: If `proba` is declared as an NSString, why do you show it being either an array or a dictionary?

Comment: Just to see in debugger sth, I had NSLog

Comment: Again, if `proba` is declared as an NSString, why does the debugger show it as an array or dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, however I'm guessing that you have a web service which returns an array if there are multiple results, but just the result itself if there is only one, and what you want is an array of one result in the latter case.

You can address this by checking the class of the value returned by your web service using `isKindOfClass:`. In outline this might be:

```
id myWebServiceResult = ...;

if (![myWebServiceResult isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) // note the ! - not
{
   // the result is not an array, make it an array of one item
   myWebServiceResult = @[ myWebServiceResult ];
}
```

HTH

Comment: Yeah I suspected this from the start as well and it is most likely the right answer. However, the *real* right answer here would be to actually change the API if possible.